# Dashes in XML Builder

Tags: ruby, xml

Is there a way to generate xml tags with dashes in builer?

Imagine I want to generate the following XML:

```
<ninja-programmer>
    Jon Skeet
</ninja-programmer>
```

I am not able to do it like:

```
require 'builder'
data = ''
x = Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:target => data, :indent => 2)
x.instruct!
x.ninja-programmer "Jon Skeet"
```

That would confuse the parser so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try declaring it explicitly:

```
x.tag! "ninja-programmer", "Jon Skeet"
```

There is a funky way too:

```
x.send :"ninja-programmer", "Jon Skeet"
```